# Saltstack events not firing or reactor system not responding

Tags: salt-stack

I am firing events from the salt minion using the command :

```
salt-call event.send 'kubemaster/kubernetes/started' '{master_ip:"10.102.28.170"}'
```

The master has reactor config:

```
reactor:
- kubemaster/kubernetes/started:
  - /srv/reactor/testfile.sls
```

In the master debug mode I can see the event coming on the message bus but it does not show any message about rendering the sls file

```
[DEBUG   ] Gathering reactors for tag kubemaster/kubernetes/started
[DEBUG   ] Compiling reactions for tag kubemaster/kubernetes/started
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded local_cache.prep_jid
```

Is there a better way to debug?
Is there any way to check if it is even looking for the sls file?

Thanks!

Comment: run master in debug mode is enough. there must be more logs and do you mind pasting the content of '/srv/reactor/testfile.sls' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a copy/paste error, but you are missing an indentation level for the second and third lines in the reactor config that you pasted.

Comment: thanks!
found that out after some time. 
wonder why it won't show up in salt master debug mode.